# I am getting issue in html default date calendar placeholder. I am getting dd-----yyyy format in place of placeholder

Tags: html, angular

I used default placeholder value as dd-----yyyy but I got date like 16-Mar-1997 after selecting the date.I want to change default date placeholder as dd/mmm/yyyy without using datepicker.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show us a [mcve] that shows us your current solution and what you have tried so far.

Comment: We get 05/23/2019 format In html input date field by default with mm/dd/yyyy placeholder. I want to change this default format to dd/MMM/yyyy in angular project without using angular material

Answer (score 0):

Then You can set dateFormat as per you want by using below code you can edit as per you want

```
For Formatting in mm-dd-yyyy

 aa=date.split("-")

 date=aa[1]+'-'+aa[2]+'-'+aa[0]
```